# Codeigniter - combine logic from two model methods

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, loops

Anyway, I had to get a database for some work stuff, and as per suggestion from a friend of mine I started making it as a website, using MySQL and the Codeigniter framework.
So far so good, I've got prety much everything up and running, but today I felt like changing something on one of the views and I'm not being able to figure out how to do it in what I think it would be the most elegant way.

This is a view for a table showing the results of different lab analysis for a single main entry reccord, independently of the different labs it was run through:

Controller

```
function ver()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('id_user') != '') {
        $id_geral = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['i'] = 1;
        $this->load->model('entradanimal_model');
        $data['main_content'] = 'descritivo';
        $data['analises'] = $this->entradanimal_model->get_descritivo_analises($id_geral);
        $data['labs'] = $this->entradanimal_model->get_labs();
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);}
    else {
            redirect('login');
        };
```

Model:

```
function get_descritivo_analises($id_geral)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT resultados.*, analises.* FROM resultados, analises WHERE resultados.id_geral='" . $id_geral . "' AND resultados.id_analises=analises.id_analises ORDER BY cast(substring_index(resultados.numerointerno, '/', - 1) AS signed INTEGER), cast(substring_index(resultados.numerointerno, '/', 1) AS signed INTEGER) ASC");
    return $query->result();
}
function get_labs()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM labs ORDER BY nome_lab");
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<table border="1|0" class="table-hover" align="center">
    <?php foreach ($analises as $s) {
        echo '<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="150" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Nº</th>
        <th width="150" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Nº Interno</th>
        <th width="150" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Data da Análise</th>
        <th width="250" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Análise</th>
        <th width="150" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Técnico Responsável</th>
        <th width="50" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Ver</th>
        <th width="50" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Editar</th>
        <th width="50" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle">Lâminas</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <td rowspan="4" class="center" style="...">'. $i++ .'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$s->numerointerno.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$s->datadiagnostico.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$s->metodo.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$s->tecnicoresponsavel.'</td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="center" style="vertical-align: middle;"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="..." href="/descritivo_lab/ver/'.$s->id_resultados.'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="center" style="vertical-align: middle;"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="..." href="/update_consulta/edit_lab/'.$s->id_resultados.'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
            <td rowspan="4" class="center" style="vertical-align: middle;"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="..." href="/entrada_laminas/add_laminas/'.$s->id_resultados.'/'.$r->id_geral.'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="center" style="...">Resultado Lupa</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="center">'.$s->lupa.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="center" style="...">Resultado Macro</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="center">'.$s->macro.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="center" style="...">Resultado Micro</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="center">'.$s->micro.'</td>
        </tr>';
    } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I wanted was to get this, but then separate it on the view into different tabs, according to the different labs. I can do this if I create a different array on the controller function for each lab:

```
$data['lab1'] = $this->entradanimal_model->get_descritivo_analises($id_geral, 1);
```

and changing the model to:

```
function get_descritivo_analises($id_geral, $id_labs){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT resultados.*, analises.* FROM resultados, analises WHERE resultados.id_geral='" . $id_geral . "' AND resultados.id_labs='" . $id_labs . "' AND resultados.id_analises=analises.id_analises ORDER BY cast(substring_index(resultados.numerointerno, '/', - 1) AS signed INTEGER), cast(substring_index(resultados.numerointerno, '/', 1) AS signed INTEGER) ASC");
    return $query->result_array();}
}
```

but I'd like to know if and how I could do this a bit more dynamically, any ideas?

EDIT:

What I mean is doing something like

```
$labs = $this->entradanimal_model->get_labs();
```

and then

```
foreach($labs['id_labs'] as $something) {
..... $this->entradanimal_model->get_descritivo_analises($id_geral, $something)
```

where the model function is something in the likes of what I wrote above:

```
function get_descritivo_analises($id_geral, $id_labs){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT resultados.*, analises.* FROM resultados, analises WHERE resultados.id_geral='" . $id_geral . "' AND resultados.id_labs='" . $id_labs . "' AND resultados.id_analises=analises.id_analises ");
    return $query->result_array();}
}
```

allowing me to differentiate the data I'm pasting to the view according to the $id_labs column, so I could then have the view generate the different tabs accordingly.

Comment: just noticed an extra <tr> on the view which wasnt doing anything, and I could probably have excluded some of the stuff from the controller, which isnt relevant for this issue

Comment: Then use the "edit" link to update your question.

Comment: sorry, didnt see the edit option at first

Comment: I don't understand with "a bit more dynamically". If you can explain it further, it would be easier.

Comment: In a way I wouldnt have to add a different "$data['lab1'], $data['lab2'], etc" for each lab, but instead in a way that I could get all the info on lets say a "$data[labs]" and then do a "foreach($id_labs as $something)" on the view and generate the different tabs with the respective results.
and in a way which would allow me to add a new lab to the labs table and having it generating the view accordingly without having me edditing the controller.
I'm sure I'm not being very explicit, but this is still all a bit too confusing for me

Comment: I've edited the post.
I'm confident that what I want to do is possible, I'm just clueless on how to do it (among other things lol) :s